# Google Sheets - Macro doesn´t copy the format of a Chart to another Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am on Google Sheets,

I am trying to copy a Chart from a Sheet1 to Sheet2 using a Macro.

When I Run it, the values from the chart do copy from Sheet1 to Sheet2 but not the formating, it appears that it puts the default Google Sheets Formating to the chart that was created by the macro.

I want to know how do I inherit the same format form the chart from Sheet1 to Sheet2.

[image]

```html
function PRUEBA2MOVERGRAF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Y80').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Tablas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('K561').activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Gráficos\'!B74:O76'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('annotations.total.enabled', true)
  .setOption('legend.position', 'bottom')
  .setOption('isStacked', 'absolute')
  .setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.fontSize', 24)
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#1a1a1a')
  .setOption('subtitleTextStyle.color', '#999999')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.fontSize', 20)
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.bold', true)
  .setXAxisTitle('')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.0.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setOption('series.0.dataLabelPlacement', 'center')
  .setOption('series.0.targetAxisIndex', 0)
  .setOption('series.0.textStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('series.0.textStyle.fontSize', 24)
  .setOption('series.0.textStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('series.1.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.1.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setOption('series.1.dataLabelPlacement', 'center')
  .setOption('series.1.targetAxisIndex', 0)
  .setOption('series.1.textStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('series.1.textStyle.fontSize', 24)
  .setOption('series.1.textStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('height', 445)
  .setOption('width', 847)
  .setPosition(561, 11, 85, 7)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('\'Gráficos\'!B74:O76'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('annotations.total.enabled', true)
  .setOption('legend.position', 'bottom')
  .setOption('isStacked', 'absolute')
  .setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.fontSize', 24)
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#1a1a1a')
  .setOption('subtitleTextStyle.color', '#999999')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.fontSize', 20)
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.bold', true)
  .setXAxisTitle('')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.0.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setOption('series.0.dataLabelPlacement', 'center')
  .setOption('series.0.targetAxisIndex', 0)
  .setOption('series.0.textStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('series.0.textStyle.fontSize', 24)
  .setOption('series.0.textStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('series.1.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.1.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setOption('series.1.dataLabelPlacement', 'center')
  .setOption('series.1.targetAxisIndex', 0)
  .setOption('series.1.textStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('series.1.textStyle.fontSize', 24)
  .setOption('series.1.textStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('height', 445)
  .setOption('width', 847)
  .setPosition(558, 8, 47, 0)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  spreadsheet.getRange('R561').activate();
};
```

Comment: I cannot understand about the relationship between your question and your script in your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this script in order to copy the chart:

```
function copyChart() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  let charts = sheet1.getCharts();
  sheet2.insertChart(charts[0]); 
}
```

The above script gets all the charts from the `Sheet1` by using the `getCharts` method. As for copying the chart, assuming the chart in question is the first one in  the `charts` array, the `insertChart` method with the `charts[0]` has been used.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcharts);
- [Apps Script Shet Class - insertChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart).